# How can I set axis ranges in ggplot2 when using a log scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a time series of data where the measurements are all integers between 1e6 and 1e8: website hits per month. I want to use ggplot2 to chart these with points and lines, but mapping the measurements to a log scale. Something like this:

```
qplot(month, hits, data=hits.per.month, log="y")
```

When I do that, ggplot seems to set the scale from 1e6 to 1e8. I want it to scale from 0 to 1e8. The natural way of doing this seems to have no affect on the output:

```
qplot(month, hits, data=hits.per.month, log="y", ylim=c(0, 100000000))
```

I can get the picture I want by transforming hits before it reaches qplot, but that changes the labels on the axis:

```
qplot(month, log10(hits), data=hits.per.month, log="y", ylim=c(0, 8))
```

I also tried various combinations with `scale_y_log10`, but had no luck.

So, how do I set the Y axis range when using a log scale in ggplot2?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Much of **ggplot2** is simply clearer to me if one doesn't use `qplot`. That way you aren't cramming everything into a single function call:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y = seq(1e6,1e8,length.out = 10))

ggplot(data = df,aes(x = x, y =y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_y_log10(limits = c(1,1e8))
```

[image]

I'm going to assume you didn't really mean a y axis minimum of 0, since on a log scale that, um, is problematic.

Comment: Thanks. That works for me. Though I wish I understood _why_ that worked and the `qplot` version does not.

Comment: How did you get the values on the y-axis to be expressed with superscripts like that?

Comment: How could I add dashes between each number on the y axis for better visibility (in ggplot) ?