# ggplot2: log10-scale and axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basically like this question:

[How can I set axis ranges in ggplot2 when using a log scale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231885/how-can-i-set-axis-ranges-in-ggplot2-when-using-a-log-scale)

The issue I have with the solution and ggplot2 it seems that it overdraws. I want `limits = c(1,1e8)` I do not want the tiny bit additional space below and above this limits. See below:

[image: wrong limits]

I want the limits to be at the edge of the graph and 0 additional space. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(data = df,aes(x = x, y =y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(1,1e8), expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
+ scale_y_log10(limits = c(1, 1e8), expand = c(0, 0))
```

although personally, I think the extra spacing serves a purpose.